Is "She played good" a grammatically correct sentence?
As far as I understand, "good" is an adjective and "well" an adverb. Therefore,

She played good.

is incorrect and should instead be

She played well.

However, I am a tennis fan and I watch a lot of player interviews and press conferences. I have noticed more and more that some American English native speakers use the sentence

She/He played good.

when describing how their opponent played during their match.
Is this a grammatical mistake, or is it some kind of exception to the rule above which I am not aware of? The closest thing I could find is the "linking verbs" exception where it is okay to use "good" as an adverb, as in:

It tastes good.

However as far as I know this doesn't apply to the verb "play".
Example of native speaker using

She played really good.


When an adjective form is used as an adverb, it's called a flat adverb They are much more commonly used in the U.S. than in England. And there are rules for when you can and can't use them, but since grammarians think they're all ungrammatical, I don't know if anybody ahs written down the grammar of flat adverbs.

Closely related to but not identical to: What is the difference between "good" and "well"

It's usually possible to come up with a contrived example where grammar that seems wrong is actually correct. For example "She played good" could mean "She played a good character" or could mean "She played against the team whose official name is 'good' with a lowercase g".

It doesn't have to be that contrived. Many adjectives could be used to convey a sense of "pretending to be ..." rather than "playing in a ... manner".

Sure, if your speech is dialectal or unschooled.

Another interesting example: "They came to do good; they stayed and did well"--said of American missionaries who settled in Hawaii and became rich. In this case "doing good" was meant to be helping the native Hawaiians, "doing well" was helping themselves.

Example

@PeterShor There are plenty of flat adverbs that nobody finds objectionable; fast is one of them. Works on descriptive grammar absolutely cover these.

@alphabet: Do these works explain why to fast go is unacceptable, while to quickly go is fine?

@PeterShor Yes! There are a large number of rules around adverb positioning and they tend to be somewhat arbitrary. Some adverbs are restricted to "final position" in a clause. Note that "to play well" is fine, but "to well play" isn't; "fast" is like "well" in that regard, but "quickly" isn't.

Good is never an adverb. Sense verbs take adjectives not adverbs. My sandwich tastes good, your idea sounds good, that dress looks good on you. All those are adjectival uses not adverbial uses.

@tchrist Many (I think most) major dictionaries list it as one, with a note describing it as "informal."

Why is everyone writing such low-level comments?

It is not a grammatical error, it's just colloquial language. You have noticed correctly that this occurs in AmE. OED labels it so:

Now chiefly North American colloquial. (c. 1275)

‘What kind of a piece is that in that case?’ ‘A short rifle.’ ‘Will she shoot good?’ ‘Yes.’ (F. L. Olmsted, Journey through Texas ii. 59, 1857).


DailyWritings explains that

Both words [well and good] can function adverbially, but the use of good as an outright adverb declined in British English in the seventeenth century. It resurfaced in the nineteenth century as an Americanism, as noted in Bartlett’s American Dictionary (1859):

English travellers have repeatedly noticed the adverbial use of this word [good]. ‘He cannot read good.’ ‘It does not shoot good.’



About its usage in sport, Merriam-Webster’s Dictionary of English Usage (pp. 480-481) says:


He treats me good expresses more appreciation than He treats me well, and She scolded him, but good can hardly be expressed with well at all. —Bolinger 1980

The justice of Bolinger’s observation is nowhere better illustrated than in the world of American professional sports, where good is the emotionally charged adverb of choice.
Our evidence shows that adverbial good is common in the speech of the less educated, but is also known and used by the better educated. It is almost de rigueur in professional sports. Bernstein 1977 reports that the adverb as used in sports grates on Edwin Newman (1974). But it does not grate on Reggie Jackson or Tony Armas or Billie Jean King, the ones who know the lingo. And one should not assume that well is avoided out of ignorance—a professional basketball coach interviewed on television after a game began by saying that the team played good but in mentioning the contributing factors said that they shot well and they rebounded well. The nuances here are plain to sports fans but are overlooked by usage writers.
As the quotations above suggest, adverbial good is still primarily a speech form. Our evidence is mostly from reported or fictional speech, letters, and similar breezy and familiar contexts. It is not likely to be needed in a book review or a doctoral dissertation.

The bottom line is that in formal contexts some will cringe at the adverbial usage of good, whereas in informal contexts it is perfectly fine.
Note that when used with linking verbs good is an adjective (Predicate Complement, describing the Subject). (See Dictionary.com's Well vs. Good and M-W's Good vs. Well: Usage Guide)

It absolutely is a grammatical error. However, it is also colloquial language. Those two things are not in conflict, as the first sentence of your answer seems to imply.

@CodyGray It's only a grammatical error when speaking/writing in a formal register. In my experience, it's so common in colloquial speech that it's no longer an error there by dint of sheer usage.

@JoshGrosso It's at least enough of an error that it's a joke in Zoolander (the fact that it's not a smart, or at least educated, thing to say is part of the joke).

@yshavit Yeah, I'm guessing that the joke mostly comes from the fact that we implicitly expect building names to sound "formal." Although, I should admit that "children who read good" sounds much worse to me than "children who read really good," for some reason. I wonder if "really" makes a significant difference for anyone else as well....

@JoshGrosso There's another example of "good used as adverb underscores the fact that the character isn't very smart" in this Always Sunny clip (that clip is fine, but the full video is NSFW!). As with many things, there's a subjective element to this; but imo, "good" as an adverb is one of those "on the verge" constructs that's sometimes okay in colloquial speech, but often sounds wrong even colloquially.

@CodyGray Generally in descriptive grammar we wouldn't consider this ungrammatical, since the adverbial good is widely used by native speakers, the sentence is free of any subtle syntactic issues, and this sort of adjective-to-adverb conversion is a productive word-formation process.

"Good" can be used as an adverb, although some people would disagree with this assertion. See Merriam-Webster for more information:

good 3 of 3 adverb

: well

he showed me how good I was doing—
Herbert Gold
Good vs. Well: Usage Guide
Adverbial good has been under attack from the schoolroom since the 19th century. Insistence on well rather than good has resulted in a split in connotation: well is standard, neutral, and colorless, while good is emotionally charged and emphatic. This makes good the adverb of choice in sports.
"I'm seeing the ball real good" is what you hear —
Roger Angell


When I was a lad one could get a "good-paying" job. Today one can only find "well-paying" jobs. That's still jarring to my ear, even if it is correct

Sample sentence:
"She played good". The use of good as an adverb is part of the vernacular in several American regions/groups. It is non standard as the standard adverb is "well". However, it is not "sub" standard as McWhorter pointed out.

Like any native dialect, a vernacular has an internally coherent
system of grammar. It may be associated with a particular set of
vocabulary, and spoken using a variety of accents, styles, and
registers.[6] As American linguist John McWhorter describes about a
number of dialects spoken in the American South in earlier U.S.
history, including older African-American Vernacular English, "the
often nonstandard speech of Southern white planters, nonstandard
British dialects of indentured servants, and West Indian patois, [...]
were nonstandard but not substandard."[7]


In other words, the
adjective "nonstandard" should not be taken to mean that these various
dialects were intrinsically incorrect, less logical, or otherwise
inferior, only that they were not the socially perceived norm or
mainstream considered prestigious or appropriate for public speech;
however, nonstandard dialects are indeed often stigmatized as such,
due to socially-induced post-hoc rationalization.[8] Again, however,
linguistics regards all varieties of a language as coherent, complex,
and complete systems—even nonstandard varieties.

vernacular
(Please note: What the uniniated do not realize is that even nonstandard dialects have rules. So, for example, if you get an utterance like: "Them boys been down in the holler". [Standard: "Those boys have been down in the hollow."] which is part of the regular speech of a southerner in the backwoods of Kentucky, saying this: "Those boys been down in the holler" could be out-of-step with the dialect.)

In addition to being an adjective, “good” can also be a noun,

good
2 of 3
noun

a: something that is good
b 1. something conforming to the moral order of the universe
   2. praiseworthy character : goodness
c: a good element or portion

a: advancement of prosperity or well-being

the good of the community


it's for your own good

b: something useful or beneficial

it's no good trying


a: something that has economic utility or satisfies an economic want



(Merriam-Webster Dictionary)
Note that M-W actually has several more definitions I’ve elected not to include—several more follow on the theme of “good for sale” which is clearly another meaning entirely, and then definition “3 of 3” is the adverbial usage of “good” as a synonym for “well” that the question rejects.
My point is that “good”—in the sense of doing the right thing, improving things, “goodness,” can be used as a noun, which can “properly” be the object of a verb.
The quintessential example of this is “to do good,” as opposed “to do well.” There is nothing grammatically wrong with “to do good,” it just means something different from “to do well.” Doing well means performing to a high standard. Doing good means taking actions that improve things.
(A distinction frequently highlighted, especially by those who might otherwise insist upon “well”—the ending of the final episode of Boy Meets World provides an excellent and heartwarming example.)
This means that “she played good” could be used to mean “she played goodness,” which is certainly odd—I’m not sure, out of context, if it’s supposed to mean that she was faking being good, or if she was playing goodness as a role in a play, and even in context it’d be a weird way to say either of those things. But it’s not a grammatical error, it’s just an awkward and unusual (and often ambiguous) wording.

I feel it's more likely that the form of 'done good' with the noun sort of leaked into 'done good' to mean 'done well' then transferred into other verbs rather than the other verbs actually using 'good' as a noun.

Basically, it's language on the move. 'Winning the game of tennis, she played good' is grammatically incorrect, and well should be the substitute for good.
However, leaving out implied words sort of justifies it - 'Winning the game, she played good tennis. As one certainly wouldn't say 'she played well tennis', except that 'she played tennis well' is quite acceptable.
Well is generally seen as an adverb (except for the hole in the ground...), whereas good is more generally used as an adjective. But more and more being used as an adverb, so eventually, like so many other words, will become accepted - if it's not already.
EDIT: I've not a clue about native American English speakers - this is written from a British English speaking pov. But it does appear to be becoming more prevalent in England, usually amongst the younger generation. Don't think quality of education comes into the equation at all...

Winning the game of tennis, she played good/well doesn't make any sense.

@user405662 - which is what I didn't quote. She played well as the alternative does.

Don't you think your version with either of the two words means "After winning the game of tennis, she played well/good"? That's what I'm asking.

@user405662 - certainly not. Common parlance these days says 'good' is acceptable, I say it's not the best, it's simply not good grammar. But if/when used enough, it'll be accepted - but still not by pedantic me.
